# Service Fabric / Actor Pattern for List of Things

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, azure-service-fabric

**Conceptually, I have the following objects:**

- `Item - (ItemId, Name, Color)`
- `ItemGroup = (GroupId, Name, Item list)`

Let's pretend items can belong to multiple groups and that Item identity and the ItemActor is necessary.

**For *stateful* actors, I have this:**

- `ItemActor (ItemId) : Get() -> returns ItemContract { ItemId, Name, Color }`
- `ItemGroupActor (GroupId) : Get() -> returns GroupContract { GroupId, Name, List< ItemContract > }`

**Here's the questions:**

1. Should the GroupActor only keep the ItemIds, and force someone else to call each ItemActor (**in a loop**) for the ItemContracts?
2. Or does the GroupActor keep all of the item details and listen for Item change events to keep his data up to date (like a view)?
3. Or is there a third "ViewActor" who compiles the data together, calling ItemActors (**in a loop**), and listening to events to keep it's data up to date?
4. Or something else?

**None of these options strike me as particularly attractive, because they either require looping actor calls, or high maintenance item management via events.**

Is there some guideline to reassure me one way or the other or for a general approach to this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You should be able to retrieve an ItemContract directly from corresponding actor, by its ID. And perform any changes on these items directly through their actors, otherwise I don't understand the decision to use actors here for ItemContract.

2) It is possible, but looks like a Reliable Service is a better collection here. Actor will be single-threaded even for events, so you would not handle updates simultaneously. That will cause poor performance.

3) Just let any single actor for ItemContract be called and used to serve updates on ItemContracts and let any single actor responsible for ItemGroup be called and used for work with groups only.

Think about Tasks — you don't have to use loops, you can work with actors(at least retrieve their state) in parallel.

Think about third service that will map Group actors to Item actors. Just mapping. No state updates, no event tracking. However, want to warn you that storing of lists in any kind of Reliable dictionary — is a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you for responding!  It's lonely out in Service Fabric land :)  I understand what you are saying.  I've definitely considered these approaches.  My problem is that the group will reference lots and lots of items.   Would you still suggest hitting each item actor in this case?  I could page the results somehow, and limit the number you can pull, perhaps...

Comment: @Tbone it depends. If you need these actors alive almost all the time and you can afford such cluster capacities to effectively distribute partitions among nodes, then it's okay to call each actor to retrieve its state, if that state has relatively small size. Probably there is a place for some cache system. If you want to save resources, than actors are not for you and you can try to store the whole actor's state in a reliable dictionary. If in this case you will face performance issues with writing to the same state, then SF is not for you.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Microsoft documentation loosely suggests that you can query a whole lot of actors efficiently (and in parallel).  This in part requires a leap of faith on my end to shift my mindset from how I usually view service calls as having overhead or expensive.  I still think the volume I'm working with is high enough to warrant more thinking.  I appreciate the help!